# Is it possible to useModel Binding to update an object when not all form values are present?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I am implementing some basic Model Binding to populate an object passed into an Action (normal use). The first Action is a CREATE method, in this case I REQUIRE all parameters be present.

For this other Action however it is simply an UPDATE method, in this case I will accept all form values, but I also want it to be possible to only receive ONE or a handful of them and thereby only update the specified fields.

I believe I would have to somehow have them default to null or "" when no value is present. However, I am under the impression that the Model Bind requires ALL of the parameters be in the POST in order to resolve the Action that takes that object.

Is this possible and I achieve it using the same Model object or will I need to make a 'full version' and a 'partial version'?

**EDIT:** Trying to make this more clear:

Right now if I have this Action:

> public ActionResult MyAction(MyObject obj)

and the MyObject object has 3 variables: var1, var2, and var3

then if I POST to MyAction and only include var1 and var2, it will not resolve because the Model Binding didn't find the var3

However, I want it to work this way! That way if someone wants to ONLY post var1 (along with some ID) I can look up the object in the database and UPDATE var1 of the object while leaving var2 and var3 alone, I am just trying to figure out how to get the Model Binding to resolve properly when form values are missing.

Comment: Your question makes no sense to me. Maybe if you showed some code it would become a little more comprehensible.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov added more detail

Comment: what do you want it to resolve to? `var3` was not being sent in the request so the model binder resolves it to the best possible value: `null`. I don't see what problem are you having with that?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov That's exactly how I want it to behave but when I try I actually get "No parameterless constructor defined for this object."

Comment: For which object are you getting this exception? `MyObject`? If this is the case you have two possibilities: 1. add a default constructor (good practice for your view models anyway) or 2. write a custom model binder for the `MyObject` type.

Comment: Looks like I had added a constructor to my Controller which broke the model binding, I was using it to initialize a variable passed from a custom [AuthorizeFilter]... now I'm not sure how I am going to do that.

Comment: what are you talking about? I have hard time following you. The initial question you have posted has nothing to do with your comments. Here's what I would suggest you: update your question, show your code, explain clearly what you are trying to achieve, ... ask a real question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Bind` attribute to whitelist the properties you expect to be posted.  This will tell the model binder to only bind the field you specified.

```
public ActionResult MyAction([Bind(Include = "Field3,Field4")MyObject myObject)
```

The normal case for an update to a subset of fields is to fetch the MyObject from the database fully filled out and call UpdateModel using the overload with the whitelist of fields to update.

```
[HttpPost]    
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    var myObject = GetMyObjectFromDatabase();
    TryUpdateModel(myObject, string.Empty /* prefix */, "Field3,Field4");
    // myObject now has Field3 and Field4 values from the POST
}
```